# React Native Expo : Modify VPN Proxy

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-firebase

My costumer uses Firebase as database which is restricted in his country.

How can i modify and set a **Proxy** to access a **restricted database**?

How can i do that ?

I don't have any idea about it
Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.